# Не срабатывает js код

Tags: javascript

В одной статье нашел код выпадающего меню:

```
http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/48342-js-raskryvayushhijjsya-spisok.html
```

перенес на jsfiddle, но меню УЖЕ выпало... Подскажите в чем там промах?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/72bxc9Lq/)

Comment: поиск ошибок можно начинать с консоли браузера

Comment: @Grundy кажется пора создавать вопрос-ответ по поводу отлова ошибок, включая советы по отладке и консоли..... он будет популярен для ссылания в комментах и ответах)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне, кстати, кажется, что уже какой-то подобный вопрос был

Comment: @АлексейШиманский классная идея, поддерживаю :D

Comment: @VostokSisters не без некоторых проблем, но вроде получилось: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482) ... Надеюсь туда будут еще добавлять ответы..... а общий сборник будет (надеюсь) тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701489/191482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Промах в том, что надо подключать [Jquery](https://jquery.com/)

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("ul").hide();
     $("ul li:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
     $(".box h3").click(function(){
         $(this).next().slideToggle();
         var text = $("span",this).text();
         $("span",this).text(text != "+" ? "+" : "-")
     });
 });
```

```css
#center {
     width: 260px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 25px;
     }
 #headline {
      text-align: center;
     }
 .box {
     width: 250px;
     margin: 10px auto;
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
     padding: 4px;
     font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd;
     }
 h3 {
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #efefef 0%,#e0e0e0 100%);
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #efefef),color-stop(1, #e0e0e0));
     border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
     color: #c1c1c1;
     font-size: 13px;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
     margin:0;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
 h3 span {
     float: right;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
 h3 span:hover {
     text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #a1eeff;
     }
 ul {
     padding: 5px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin:0;
     }
 ul li {
     font-size: 13px;
     list-style-type: square;
     list-style-position: inside;
     color: #a1a1a1;
     padding: 5px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
     <div id="headline">
         Раскрывающийся список на jQuery
     </div>
         <div id="center">
             <div class="box">
                 <h3>Список №1<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
                 <ul>
                     <li>Пункт №1</li>
                     <li>Пункт №2</li>
                     <li>Пункт №3</li>
                     <li>Пункт №4</li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```