# Средства и методы нахождения ошибок в коде их исправления. Сборник

Tags: отладка, любой-язык, обработка-ошибок, faq

Этот вопрос, по аналогии с вопросом [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/191482), предназначен для того, чтобы в единственном общем ответе собрать ссылки на вопросы-ответы по методам поиска, нахождения и исправления ошибок в коде.

В вопросы, перечисленные ниже в списке **МОЖНО и нужно добавлять еще ответы!**

Метки пишем в алфавитном порядке.

---

Люди смогут использовать его для выявления схожих проблем в различных технологиях.

Также удобно использовать в качестве списка эталонных вопросов, на которые можно сослаться при мелких несущественных ошибках и, возможно, 
закрывать вопросы как дубликат, если они о таких вещах как:

- "Что не так в коде?"
- "Где у меня ошибка?"
- "Почему программа не работает?"
- и подобные

Comment: Можно отнести к методики отлавливания ошибок: Unit-testing  и еще сборка проектов с помощью Jenkins, Travis или тругих CI систем? Или это больше относиться к проектам?

Comment: @Дениc вообще изначально была идея собрать вещи совсем примитивного плана, для совсем новичков, которые приходят с банальными вопросами типа "Почему код не работает?" и даже не знают о самых простых вещах как то консоль или отладке или вообще даже о IDE. Пока не могу что-то сказать. Но если захочется написать вопрос-ответ по данным видам, то одна просьба - не в  те существующие вопросы, где инфа совсем для новичков)) а отдельным. ну и в список потом его добавить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский имхо, но мне кажется нет смысла тратить время на новичком когда куча вопросов уровня выше новенький валяться без ответа, просто изучить отладчик это вопрос пару дней, да и от повторения это не спасет (хотя скорее всего в этом плане я не прав). Потому как в новички очень невнимательны из-за отсутствия опыта работы с кодом. А вот как раз примеры для опытных людей которые допустим знакомы с Jenkins и хотели бы пример для Travis вполне актуальны. Часто захожу на stackoverflow просто что-бы посмотреть свои старые вопросы или ответы.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это мета-вопрос / сборник ссылок на другие вопросы, а не самостоятельный вопрос.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Общие практики и советы

- [Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701817/191482)

## Список по языкам

- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/191482)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482)
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)
- [css](/questions/tagged/css) [Что делать, если не работает css-класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/183314)