# Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?

Tags: отладка, любой-язык, обработка-ошибок

При разработке часто могут возникать разного рода ошибки, а у меня нет знаний о том как и с помощью чего можно было бы их обнаруживать или упреждать. Даже мелкие ошибки. Поэтому часто задаю вопросы в формате *"Где ошибка в коде?"* на разных ресурсах, вместо того, чтобы самостоятельно всё исправить.

Так как общие инструменты и практики есть во всех языках, то хотелось бы все их узнать, от простых до сложных. Напишите, пожалуйста, какие способы есть?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой ответ будет про **IDE**.

**IDE** (англ. Integrated Development Environment - Интегрированная среда разработки). Их очень много. Например часто используют:

- для [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) — *Visual Studio*
- для [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) — *WebStorm*, *NetBeans*, *Eclipse*, *Brackets*, *Sublime* и т.д.
- для [php](/questions/tagged/php) — *PHPStorm*, *NetBeans*, *Eclipse* и т.д.
- для [java](/questions/tagged/java) — *Intellij IDEA*
- для других языков еще что-то

В *IDE* много бесконечных возможностей, например:

- детектор дублируемого кода
- рефакторинг
- инструменты для работы с базами данных
- интеграция с системами управления версиями
- **автодополнение кода**
- **подсветка синтаксиса**
- **подсказки при наборе кода** (функции, ключевые слова, переменные, которые объявлял ранее)
- и многое другое

**Как это поможет?**

Среда знает, что она редактирует код и знает язык, на котором написан код. В неё встроен синтаксический анализатор языка программирования.

Еще на самом первом этапе написания кода она может показать строки с банальными (и не только) ошибками, но которые **уже** могут привести к нерабочему или неправильно функционирующему коду.

*IDE* показывает номер строки кода, где предположительно ошибка; краткое и полное описание ошибки, которое можно прочитать, проанализировать и исправить. Ошибки показываются как на боковой панели, так и в самом редакторе **еще на этапе написания**, а для компилируемых языков еще и в консоли при запуске программы.

Примеры:

*Visual Studio*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Intellij IDEA*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*WebStorm* и *PHPStorm*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сразу видеть:

- уровень ошибки  (предупреждение, уведомление, ошибка)
- полный текст ошибки
- в каком файле
- номер строки, на которой ошибка

Можно перейти в скрипт на указанную строку и проанализировать.

#### **Не знаете английский?**

Откройте любой онлайн переводчик и скопируй туда текст ошибки заменив заглавные буквы на строчные:

*C#*

> CS0103    The name 'getSum' does not exist in the current context ConsoleApp2017  C:\VS\ConsoleApp2017\Program.cs 6

```
Имя «getSum» не существует в текущем контексте
ConsoleApp2017  в файле C:\VS\ConsoleApp2017\Program.cs 
На линии №6
```

Не может найти метод `getSum` в классе `Program.cs` на линии 6. Значит вызов есть, а объявления нет и искать надо в указанном направлении.

*Java*

> Error:(34, 9) java: cannot find symbol
>    symbol:   method getSum()
>    location: class test.Test

```
Ошибка: (34, 9) java: не удается найти символ
Символ: метод getSum ()
Местоположение: класс test.Test
```

и так далее.

Исправлять желательно **все** ошибки, как минимум уровня опасности "красный". `warning` и `notice` могут быть временно забыты, например сообщение о неиспользованной переменной, которую вы точно намерены потом использовать. Но в итоге надо починить их все!

---

В *IDE* еще много полезных и не упомянутых возможностей. Для их использования: - определись с языком, подбери нужную *IDE* и изучай.

Comment: Это скорее относится к синтаксическим ошибкам... По крайней мере мне кажется, что ничего нового по сравнению с диагностикой того же компилятора командной строки тут не описано. А ошибки проектирования? Логические ошибки? Ошибки времени выполнения? Да мало ли в Бразилии... пардон, в программе может встретиться ошибок. Надо бы все же и возможности отладчика упомянуть, нет?

Comment: Так точно. Поэтому я рассчитываю, что кто-то (надеюсь не один и не два человека) напишет еще ответы о каких-либо еще ошибках. Хотя бы которые можно на начальном этапе упреждать и не бегать с вопросами "что не так в коде" по каждой мелочи. А этот ответ я просто вынес из других, а то у меня копи-паста получилась :-/