# Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?

Tags: css, отладка, faq

Я пишу css-правило

```
.nav-users {
  color: red;
}
```

но на странице ничего не меняется: цвет остаётся серым.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Браузеры предоставляют отличные инструменты для отладки css. Не надо ждать, пока кто-то угадает, в чём проблема. Надо просто взять и посмотреть, что же происходит. Покажу на примере Хрома.

Сначала надо обновить страницу со сбросом кэша.
В большинстве браузеров это <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Если не помогло, то по исследуем по следующему плану:

1. Щёлкнуть проблемный элемент правой кнопкой и выбрать пункт <kbd>Исследовать элемент</kbd>:

   [image: Исследовать элемент]
2. Появится панель отладки, на которой на вкладке <kbd>Elements</kbd> выделен кликнутый элемент. Если нужен другой, можно перейти к нему. Затем следует обратить внимание на вкладки <kbd>Styles</kbd> и <kbd>Computed</kbd>:

   [image: Elements]
3. Если в <kbd>element.style</kbd> есть интересующее свойство, то

   - если в html-разметке прописан стиль в атрибуте `style`, удаляем оттуда лишнее
   - если нет, кончаем читать этот ответ и переходим к отладке скриптов, которые этот стиль выставляют (либо перебиваем `!important`ом, что делать крайне не рекомендуется)

   [image: style]
4. На вкладке <kbd>Styles</kbd> надо найти свой селектор.
   **Если его там нет,** то проблема в опечатке или подключении css-файла.

   [image: Класс]
5. Как видим, свойство зачёркнуто, но восклицательного знака (говорящего о неверном значении) нет. Это означает, что есть другое правило, имеющее больший приоритет. В простых случаях достаточно посмотреть на вышестоящие правила и понять, что там надо. В более запутанных стоит заглянуть на вкладку <kbd>Computed</kbd> и посмотреть, какие вообще значения влияют:

   [image: Compuded]
6. Здесь видно, что селектор `.so-header .navigation .-link` перебивает наше правило.
   Кликом по стрелочке можно перейти к самому правилу, но нам это сейчас не нужно.

   [image: Переход к правилу]
7. Теперь мы знаем, что приоритет используемого правила `0 id, 3 класса, 0 тегов`.
   Если мы уверены, что наше правило идёт после переопределяемого, то нам достаточно той же силы. Если нет, то надо побольше.

   Самый простой способ - это сделать так:

   ```
   .nav-users.nav-users.nav-users.nav-users {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   Но руководствуясь здравым смыслом, стоит всё-таки сделать так:

   ```
   .so-header .navigation .nav-users {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   или так:

   ```
   .so-header .navigation .-link.nav-users {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   Должно заработать:

   [image: Новый стиль]

   [image: И результат]
8. **Если всё равно не работает.**

   На шаге 6 стоило заглянуть в переопределяющий стиль - возможно, в нём есть `!important`:

   [image: !important]

   В таком случаем нам тоже придётся его использовать:

   ```
   .so-header .navigation .-link.nav-users {
     color: red !important;
   }
   ```

---

**Если проблемы возникают только при печати, надо включить эмуляцию `@media print`.** Для этого надо нажать в девтулах <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Sift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> и в появившемся окне написать media:

[image: попап с media]

после чего выбрать строчку *Emulate CSS print media*.

Comment: Те для кого это написано к сожалению никогда этого сами не найдут перед тем как начать писать в Q&A, но благо, что теперь есть то место куда можно отправлять xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ага. А то я уже несколько таких вопросов видел за пару дней.

Comment: Здорово ты расписал - как в школе прям

Comment: в edge и ff могут отличаться developer tools :) от того, что описано в ответе

Comment: @Grundy, могут. Но подобную ошибку можно и в хроме поотлаживать. У браузеров всё хорошо с приоритетами селекторов.