# Как правильно прописать CSS-стили для 3 абзацев для нужного отображения в Яндекс.почта

Tags: html, css, outlook

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 1px;">Есть такой код</p>
<p style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">И вот такая строчка есть</p>
<p style="margin-top: 1px;">Ну и еще одна строка</p>
```

[image: это яндекс.почта]

это яндекс-почта

Comment: вот  только недавто был подобный вопрос  почитай   https://tj-s.ru/tod/verstka-pisem.-polnaya-versiya.html

Comment: Попробуй не использовать px?

Comment: это я его задавал. Мне нужен ответ на простой вопрос: почему при margin-top: (любое значение ) и margin-bottom(любое значение), установленных одновременно к одному элементу, например <p>, пропадает одно из них, когда код уже на яндекс.почте и mail.ru, кстати такая же песня

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988 + margin collapse - у тебя расстояние между каждой парой абзацев составляет 1em как максимальное из браузерного 1em у одного из них и какого-то значения, прописанного у второго.

Comment: @Proshka, воспользуйся какой-нибудь почтовой программой и посмотри, что реально есть в коде письма. Покажи, какую разметку ты отправляешь, какая приходит в почтовый клиент, и какая показывается на сайте. Попробуй не использовать px как единицу измерения, потому что на скриншоте всё прописано в pt - возможно, так работает конвертер.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в том-то и дело, что писал подпись на Outlook - простенький код, а гемора на 2 дня принес. И не могу понять: В Outlook все красиво и ровно - как надо. На Яндексе и Mail.ru - исчезают margin-ы попеременно

Comment: @Proshka, если заменить px на pt - что-то изменится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, менял и на pt, и на em - на все, что существует - картина не меняется - если установить margin-top и margin-bottom - исчезает одно из свойств. Скоро застрелюсь

Comment: @Proshka, ну так сделай таблицей как у всех, а не мудри.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще-то подпись вся сверстана на Zurb Foundation for Emails. Все всегда красиво версталось на этом фреймворке - уже делал письма неоднократно, а вот здесь вылез такой косяк. Упростил код до трех фраз, а сдвинуть по максимуму - не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кому интересно - проблема решилась так:

```
margin: 0pt;// задание свойства одним margin для всех 4 сторон.
```

Именно так Яндекс пропустил стили и корректно их подключил. А так просто минус 2 дня из жизни...