# При добавлении сайта на хостинг появился горизонтальный скролл

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, hosting, отступы

[image: Страница]

Загрузил свой сверстанный сайт, на репозиторий гитхаба, открыл ссылку на него, и почему то появился вот такой отступ у body слева и сверху (выделен красным). В чем может быть проблема подскажите пожалуйста. Проблема появилась именно после заливки на хостинг, при верстке и отладке в браузере такого отступа не было.

Comment: После заливки в коде смотрели на наличие чего-то нового?

Comment: дай ссылку на страницу

Comment: Наверное из-за картинки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714833/178988

Comment: normalize.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). Вот такая ошибка в браузере, normilize.css не может загрузится по какой то причине, есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

У вас стили браузера выставляют margin 8px для body. Обнулите или используйте normalize.css