# css отступы на примерах

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть несколько вопросов по отступам на конкретных примерах:

1. Элементарный html-код.

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: red;">
</div>

<div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">
</div>

<div class="footer" style="background-color: green;">
</div>
```

Вопрос: откудого появляются отступы от краев? Я думал div должен занимать всю ширину.

2. Удаление отступов.

Мне удалось удалить все отступы, указав у body margin: 0. Но почему margin, а не padding? Ведь margin это отступ между элементами, а body - единственный элемент.
Логичнее было бы padding: 0.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: red;">
</div>

<div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">
</div>

<div class="footer" style="background-color: green;">
</div>
```

3. Почему добавляется отступ сверху div-а, при добавлении в него

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: red;">
    <p></p>
</div>

<div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">
</div>

<div class="footer" style="background-color: green;">
</div>
```

4. Почему пропал отступ (который появился в 3-ем пункте) и почему padding top и left отличаются? Ведь у тега р padding указано inherit?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
p {
    padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="background-color: red;">
    <p>text</p>
</div>

<div class="content" style="background-color: blue;">
</div>

<div class="footer" style="background-color: green;">
</div>
```

Comment: не легче добавить reset.css?! или наоборот это усложнит жизнь?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В спецификации HTML и CSS есть много неоговоренных вещей, которые разработчики делают как посчитают нужным. К примеру, вы практически нигде не встретите конкретное значение отступов и есть ли они вообще у элементов. В первую очередь стоит помнить, что HTML является гипертекстом и делался для нужд передачи документов.

1. Вы наверное замечали, что всякие официальные документы имеют отступы от краев, в том же `Word` или при выводе на печать? Это делается для удобства чтения, текст на краю выглядит очень плохо. Поэтому делают отступ от краев документа.
2. `Margin` - это в первую очередь отступ от края элемента до него самого. А `padding` от границы до контента, поэтому не забывайте про границы `border`(!). Поэтому логично, что данный отступ оформлен через `margin`, поскольку это правило пришло из оформления документов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Заметьте, этот отступ дает браузер как "user agent stylesheet" и разные браузеры могут давать разные отступы, размеры и прочее, что явно не указано в документации.

3. Это эффект схлопывания границ. Если у внутреннего элемента margin больше, чем у внешнего, то они оба отодвигаются от верхней границы на величину внутреннего элемента. У p от 16 и потому общий margin становится равен 16 т.к. 16 > 8 и берется больший. Причем тема схлопывания довольно специфицная, к примеру при добавлении текста, границ, отступов схлопывание пропадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите тут часть про "вложенные элементы", да и вообще всю статью: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

4. Опять же исходя из пункта 3 и эффекта схлопывания пропадает. Ну и еще есть отступы у самого `<p>`, хотя их конкретное значения в пикселях явно в документации не указано, но вы видите разницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В 3 примере вы не правы. что что вы показываете как 16 пикселей на картинке, на самом деле 32. Что касается отступов в 4 посмотрите [Мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753585/183429). И дополните ваш, так как его скорее всего примут.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin да, спасибо, я так давно с этим не сталкивался, что уже забыл как они точно работают.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, каждый элемент имеет свои отступы, при том в каждом из браузеров они могут немного отличаться. Это сделано специально чтобы когда добавляется что-то на страницу которая не имеет какого-то стиля все выглядело не слипишимся.

Для того чтобы это убрать существуют reset.css или же normalize.css ими желательно пользоваться, они убирают отступы которые не нужны и оставляют те что нужны. 
К примеру у body есть свой отступ который равняется кажись 20px он в целом никому не нужен, кроме редких случаев. Так же есть отступы margin у таких елементов как h1, p - часто грамотный дизайнер знает какой отступ у этих елементов и рисует исходя из этого.. тем самым Вам не нужно ставть отступ каждому елементу уникальный

Но... это не точно =)

Answer (score 1):

По порядку:

1. Именно так. `div` занимает всю ширину `body`. Именно это вы и видите. Отступы напрямую связаны со вторым вопросом.
2. `margin` по тому что это внешний отступ от тега `html`.
3. По тому что у тега `p` есть `margin`, однако по умолчанию `div` имеет `overflow: visible`, что позволяет `margin` тега `p` выходит за пределы `div`, так как нет границ которые будут его ограничивать, исправить это можно либо ответом из 4 вопроса (**НЕ рекомендуется**), либо добавлением `overflow: auto` или `overflow: hidden` в зависимости от того что вы желаете получить.
4. `padding-top` и `padding-left` не отличаются, они оба все еще равны 10, но у Вас все еще есть `margin`. Что касается того, почему пропал отступ сверху. По тому что padding > 1 unit (любые единицы измерения), немного изменит поведение `overflow: visible`. Если раньше `margin`, тега `p` ничего не ограничивало, то теперь есть `padding` у родительского `div`. По этому теперь стили перерисовываются с этим условием.

Answer (score 1):

> откудого появляются отступы от краев?

У `body` по умолчанию `margin: 8px`.

> Но почему margin, а не padding?

Потому что так принято. Если ты ему `position: relative` пропишешь, то absolute с нулём встанет по этому отступу, а по паддингу бы не встал:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
123456<br>
7890123
```

> body - единственный элемент

Нет, есть ещё `head`:

```css
head, style { display: block; }
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```

> Почему добавляется отступ сверху div-а, при добавлении в него

Это называется margin collapse (схлопывание марджинов). Предлагаю почитать отдельно.

> Почему пропал отступ (который появился в 3-ем пункте)

Тоже margin collapse, только на этот раз отступы не схлопываются.

> почему padding top и left отличаются?

Они не отличаются, ты просто забыл про `margin: 1em 0` по умолчанию у `p`.

PS: [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988)

Comment: `Почему пропал отступ (который появился в 3-ем пункте) - Тоже margin collapse.` Тут Вы не правы, это как раз отсутствие схлопывания.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, под margin collapse я имел в виду всю схему взаимодействия вертикальных отступов, включающую оба случая - и когда схлопывание происходит, и когда оно не происходит. Т. е. я НЕ имел в виду, что он с чем-то схлопывается.