# Как убрать эти стили у слайдера?

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте, у меня есть 2 слайдера и один должен иметь полосу прокрутку(кружочки), а другой нет  использую lightslider, как убрать у второго слайдера эти кружочки внизу. Пытался основному блоку добавить `background-image: none !important;` но не особо помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714832/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-css-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81)

Comment: @diraria я подключил библиотеку lightslider, если изменить стили к файлу к которому я подключился, то будет потеряна полоса у прокрутки первого слайдера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно ничего скрывать. Читайте [документацию по lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html)

Чтобы убрать булиты - нужно в настройках слайдера прописать:

```
pager: false
```

И как вообще свойство `background-image` должно было повлиять на них?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего скрыть только один из двух элементов поможет [селектор дочерних элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors). Выглядит он так (пробел важен):

```
селектор_родителя селектор_потомка {
    /* стили */
}
```

Таким образом, если полоса прокрутки имеет класс `rounds` и хочется её скрыть только в блоке с классом `block1`, то можно написать что-нибудь такое:

```
.block1 .rounds {
    display: none;
}
```

[Полезная статья про селекторы на learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors)