# как убрать отступы от края браузера в css-grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Слева и справа появляются оступы от границ блока до границ браузера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как избавиться от них?

Вот стили всего контейнера в котором вся верстка

```
#grid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;  /* four columns */
  grid-template-rows: auto; /* auto rows  */
}
```

Comment: можно добавить `body { margin: 0; }`, либо использовать [`normalize.css`](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). также связанный вопрос: [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/227016)

Comment: @diraria у меня прописан body{margin:0; padding:0;} все-равно есть отступы, это css-grid делает мне кажется

Comment: Ну тогда нужно больше информации, например [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вставь это:

```
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
```

Пример:

```css
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#grid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;  /* four columns */
  grid-template-rows: auto; /* auto rows  */
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
      <div class="grid">grid-item #1</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #2</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #3</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui illum eaque ipsum laudantium nihil velit, dolor quisquam ratione quidem, illo!</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #5</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #6</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #7</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #8</div>
      <div class="grid">grid-item #9</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Да ,все выровнялось спасибо! У меня вся сетка была обёрнута в article внутри которого был section с padding:0 1em; по-этому и появлялся отступ. Разобрался.