# Изменить атрибут style элемента в зависимости от значения другого

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Уже всю голову сломал.

```js
$("input[name='variants[color][]']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).parent().prev().children('.target').css("background-color", "#fff");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="height">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="target" style="background: #fff;"></div>
</li>

<li class="color">
  <input name="variants[color][]" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" />
</li>
```

Такие пары li идут один за другим, их много. Мне нужно:
если `input[name="variants[color][]"]` пустой (то есть, не заполнен), то у `div.target` поменять значение атрибута style.

Но не выходит. Как правильно?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ну у тебя и фантазия)))) Это я на счет атрибута `name="variants[color][]"`...)))))))  С чего такое название...?  Праздное любопытство)

Comment: )) Это в движке так. PHP берет значения из этих input-ов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает (кроме нулевой высоты). Если надо, чтобы оно обновлялось при изменении значения, надо подписываться на событие `input`:

```js
function updateBg() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parent().prev().children('.target').css("background-color", $this.val() ? "" : "red");
}

$("input[name='variants[color][]']").each(updateBg).on('input', updateBg);
```

```css
.target {
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="height">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="target"></div>
</li>

<li class="color">
  <input name="variants[color][]" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" />
</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не, мне не нужно по событию. Мне при загрузке страницы (вернее, после). Странное дело. В консоли я вижу эти элементы через console.log. Но после добавления .css(...) - ничего не меняется. Пишу так: ... .css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714833/178988

Answer (score 1):

Так правильно. Нужно проверять поле на изменение состояния и тогда проверять, пустое оно или нет.

```js
$("input[name='variants[color][]']").on("change, input", function(){
  $("input[name='variants[color][]']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).parent().prev().children('.target').css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
    $(this).parent().prev().children('.target').css("background-color", "gray");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.target {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="height">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="target" style="background: red;"></div>
</li>

<li class="color">
  <input name="variants[color][]" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" />
</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не, мне не нужно по событию. Мне при загрузке страницы (вернее, после). Странное дело. В консоли я вижу эти элементы через console.log. Но после добавления .css(...) - ничего не меняется. Пишу так: ... .css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");

Answer (score 1):

Всем Большое Спасибо за ответы. Все решилось оборачиванием кода функцией
 `$( document ).ready)))`

Comment: Если бы скрипты подключались после разметки, `$(document).ready` было бы необязательно.