# Добрый день. помогите найти баг в моб версии сайта

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица на сайте.она не помещается в видимую область экрана и выпадает за него. если открыть сайт на моб и затем пролистать экран влево таблица появляется, а остальной контент сверху и снизу таблицы уходит влево сохраняя свою ширину и на его месте появляется черный фон. можно ли сделать так чтобы контент расширялся? или нужно как-то изменить отображение страницы? [image: скрин]

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на код

Comment: @Yernar, не ссылку, а тут выложить. Переходить и искать - вопрос закроют. Как и этот, впрочем.

Comment: http://mobimarket96.ru/collection/remont-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирай:

1. Положи таблицу в div и задай ему `overflow-x: auto`, чтобы таблица скроллилась горизонтально внутри него.
2. Текущее поведение гораздо удобнее того, которое ты предлагаешь. Если вся страница растянется, то чтобы читать текст выше, её придётся скроллить. Можешь просто поменять фон с чёрного на белый, что было бы логично.

PS: [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте эти стили к вашей таблице:

```css
overflow-x: scroll !important;
width: auto !important;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: С каких пор overflow работает с `display: table`? И почему `width: auto`, когда должно быть `100%`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Я поэкспериментировал на самом сайте в панеле разработчиков. Все отлично работало. Со `width: 100%` тоже работает

Comment: Вот из-за этого работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr3H2.png К тому же, подозреваю, что в iOS Safari всё равно не работает.

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!! всё работает

Comment: В Сафари тоже всё ОК