# Объекты смещаются вправо на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

Не минусите сильно, я только учусь. Была задача подредактировать сайт, добавить список городов, где работает компания. На десктопе список отображается по центру как и положено. На мобильных устройствах заголовок расположен по центру, а список смещается вправо. Что поправить чтобы все было по центру. Сайт: потолок-натяжной.бел , листинг в футере. Код списка прикрепляю.

```css
.cities {
  text-align: center;
  background: #545960;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Roboto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.cities p {
  font-family: Helvetica, Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cities a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cities a:hover {
  color: #d6b460;
}
```

```html
<div class="cities">
  <p>Мы работаем в следующих городах</p>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--h1aeefu.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Минск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1aescj1g.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Гомель</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1abglpdo.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Могилев</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1ac1acci.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Гродно</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90abjlm5be.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Витебск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--90ai6aff.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Брест</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90aayernio.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Бобруйск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--80aabg4aa6aip9e.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Барановичи</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90acrxbki.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Борисов</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--h1aeigm.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Пинск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--80a1ag6a.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Орша</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--g1ajgj8ch.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Мозырь</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1ajhbodocg.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Солигорск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--80ahll.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Лида</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1aqcgfbabg7e.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Новополоцк</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--d1acqdicbd3f.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Молодечно</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--j1abibc9b.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Полоцк</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90ajhkmd.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Жлобин</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--d1adhucd.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Жодино</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1acfvdsbqchf.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Светлогорск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо избавиться от отступов у `ul`. Нужный селектор (вместо `ul`) сам подберёшь.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cities {
  text-align: center;
  background: #545960;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Roboto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.cities p {
  font-family: Helvetica, Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cities a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cities a:hover {
  color: #d6b460;
}
```

```html
<div class="cities">
  <p>Мы работаем в следующих городах</p>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--h1aeefu.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Минск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1aescj1g.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Гомель</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1abglpdo.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Могилев</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1ac1acci.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Гродно</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90abjlm5be.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Витебск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--90ai6aff.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Брест</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90aayernio.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Бобруйск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--80aabg4aa6aip9e.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Барановичи</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90acrxbki.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Борисов</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--h1aeigm.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Пинск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--80a1ag6a.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Орша</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--g1ajgj8ch.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Мозырь</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--c1ajhbodocg.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Солигорск</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--80ahll.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Лида</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1aqcgfbabg7e.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Новополоцк</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="http://xn--d1acqdicbd3f.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Молодечно</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--j1abibc9b.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Полоцк</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--90ajhkmd.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Жлобин</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--d1adhucd.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Жодино</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://xn--b1acfvdsbqchf.xn----8sbsmbfqccabgc7bh2s.xn--90ais">Светлогорск</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

PS: А вообще, включаешь в хроме эмуляцию и [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988)

Comment: Опередил=)) Также нужно убрать внутренний отступ слева. Вся проблема в том, что автор не убрал отступы у всех элементов, хотя до этого задавал вопрос точь-в-точь.

Comment: @Arthur, и тут тоже опередил)))

Comment: Тут опередил, а там победил;)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Предыдущий вопрос касался других отступов)

Comment: @Arthur, я имел в виду, что правку про padding я внёс до твоего комментария, т. е. я тебя в этом ответе дважды опередил - сначала с самим ответом, потом с паддингом :)

Comment: @AntonKuzmich, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.