# HTML contenteditable, BR меняет высоту

Tags: html, css

Tcnm `div` с такой вот разметкой:

```css
.option__input {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 0.075em solid black;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    min-width: 7em;
    max-width: 10em;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
  outline:none;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Другое</div>
<div class="option__input text text_input" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Когда первый раз вводится текст, добавляется `br` и немного увеличивает высоту.
Как можно от этого избавиться?

1. Изображение, до ввода текста:
   [image: До ввода текста]
2. Изображение, введен пробел:
   [image: Ввел пробел]

В Chrome все работает, как надо. А вот в Firefox, происходит вышеописанное.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714833/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy не совсем понимаю, чем это должно помочь?

Comment: Тут телепатов нет. Если ты приводишь код, в котором проблема не воспроизводится, то бери и дебажь тот код, в котором она воспроизводится. Скорее всего на br повешены какие-то стили (возможно даже, что в reset.css).

Comment: @Qwertiy никаких других стилей нет, а вот сейчас заметил, что такая реакция в Firefox, а Chrome отображает все как надо, в чем может быть дело?