# Прозрачный параграф закрывает контент и не даёт с ним взаимодействовать. Вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте стоит параграф поверх остальных элементов. При изменении через DevTools параграф исчезает и всё работает как надо но когда я меняю в файле ничего не меняется. Вот ссылка на [сайт](http://rom.com.kg/)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл `/wp-content/themes/parlament/style.css`

```
.mistape_caption {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Не помогает. Сделал как всё вы сказали

Comment: Ничего подобного - всё работает! Вы кеш-то сбросьте! Ctrl+F5

Comment: Здоровья вам! Живите долго и счастливо

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Этот параграф относится к модулю орфографии (Если вы нашли ошибку, пожалуйста, выделите фрагмент текста и нажмите Ctrl+Enter). Проверьте его.