# Сокращение minmax( ) в Grid Layout

Tags: css

Есть грид контейнер, что можно сделать, чтобы не писать каждый раз ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ **minmax(min-content, 15%)**
в **grid-template-columns.** Пробовал **repeat** не помогло.

```css
.main {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 display:grid;                        
 grid-gap: 15px;                     
 grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 15%)  
 minmax(min-content, 15%)  
 minmax(min-content, 15%); /* как сократить эту строку */
 
 grid-template-rows: 200% 200% 200%;   
 grid-auto-flow: column;              
}

.item_1  {
width: 100%;
background: red;
}

.item_2  {
width: 100%;
background: blue;
}

.item_3  {
width: 100%;
background: gold;
}

.item_4  {
width: 100%;;
background: gray;
}

.item_5  {
width: 100%;
background: green;
}

.item_6  {
width: 100%;
background: yellow;
}
.item_7  {
width: 100%;
background: brown;
}

.item_8  {
width: 100%;
background: orange;
}

.item_9  {
width: 100%;
background: crimson;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
  <div class="item_1"> 1 headerdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd3333333333</div>
  <div class="item_2"> 2 nav</div>
  <div class="item_3"> 3 main</div>
  <div class="item_4"> 4 aside</div>
  <div class="item_5"> 5 section</div>
  <div class="item_6"> 6 section2</div>
  <div class="item_7"> 7 section3</div>
  <div class="item_8"> 8 section4</div>
  <div class="item_9"> 9 footer</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: c repeat работает все. Как ты пробовал его использовать?

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat ( minmax (min-content, 15%) );

Comment: это неправильный синтаксис просто. Первый параметр отвечает за количество [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat())

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat (3, minmax(min-content, 15%) );  добавил первый параметр, все равно не работает, покажите правильный синтаксис

Comment: а что конкретно не работает? Отображение точно такое же как и сейчас, с ручным повторением. Попробуй добавить картинки, как должно быть, как сейчас, и как с repeat, чтобы было видно что именно выводится не так

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat (3, minmax(min-content, 15%) ); это правильный синтаксис?

Comment: так ты попробуй :)

Comment: Могли бы просто сказать да или нет. Зачем троллить?

Comment: В чем заключается троллинг? Если ты посмотрел справку и привел пример стиля - ты можешь вставить эту строку к себе. Если синтаксис будет неправильным, в devtools браузера данная строчка будет зачеркнута и не будет применяться, если правильный = значит зачеркнута не будет. Ты написал что добавил первый параметр и у тебя не работает. На предложения показать что именно не работает начал спрашивать про синтаксис. Непонятно в итоге - пробовал ты эту строку или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(min-content, 15%));
```

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(min-content, 15%));
  grid-template-rows: 200% 200% 200%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item_1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.item_2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.item_3 {
  width: 100%;
  background: gold;
}

.item_4 {
  width: 100%;
  ;
  background: gray;
}

.item_5 {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.item_6 {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.item_7 {
  width: 100%;
  background: brown;
}

.item_8 {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.item_9 {
  width: 100%;
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item_1"> 1 headerdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd3333333333</div>
  <div class="item_2"> 2 nav</div>
  <div class="item_3"> 3 main</div>
  <div class="item_4"> 4 aside</div>
  <div class="item_5"> 5 section</div>
  <div class="item_6"> 6 section2</div>
  <div class="item_7"> 7 section3</div>
  <div class="item_8"> 8 section4</div>
  <div class="item_9"> 9 footer</div>
</div>
```

> grid-template-columns: repeat (3, minmax(min-content, 15%) ); добавил первый параметр, все равно не работает

Потому что тут пробелы лишние, нельзя имя функции от скобки отделять пробелами. И хром это отлично показывает:

[image: скриншот зачёркнутого свой1ства]

Про отладку css-свойств: [Что делать, если не работает CSS-класс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988)