# Блок Div не видит кнопки button и не применяет к ним стили

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, наследование

Столкнулся с проблемой: не применяются стили  к его дочерним элементам, то есть он его не видит. Пробовал убирать лишние классы, Менять данные - все бестолку. Вот html-код:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.list {
  list-style: square;
}

.light_theme {
  background: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.scan_blocks {
  background: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  /*Задаем обтекание*/
  line-height: 40px;
  /*Высота строки +  верт. центрирования текста*/
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  /*Фиксируем ширину блока*/
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.scan_blocks_big {
  background: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  /*Задаем обтекание*/
  line-height: 40px;
  /*Высота строки +  верт. центрирования текста*/
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  /*Фиксируем ширину блока*/
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#buttons_block {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000;
  height: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Faceit Service WebSite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body class="light_theme">
  <h1 style="color: #FFFFFF;">redut</h1>
  <div id="buttons_block">
    <!-- <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks">
                    <p>Информация</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks">
                    <p>Аккаунты</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks">
                    <p>Скан</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div>
            <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks">
                    <p>Спам</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div>
            <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks">
                    <p>Блэклист</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div>
            <div class="div_button"> -->
    <button type="button" class="scan_blocks_big">
                    <p>Check_something</p>
                </button>
    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Что делать?

Comment: ну начнем с того, что вы в `#buttons_block` в значениях высоты и ширины не указали единицы измерения ( `1000px` например)

Comment: Всё применяется. А где у вас лежит main.css по отношению к html-файлу?

Comment: [Отлаживать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714833/178988) Вопрос так написан, что за тебя разбираться совершенно лень.

Comment: @TaniaLinn, cпасибо, помогло. Я новичок в веб-разработке, так что извиняйте)