# СИ, функции и двухмерные массивы

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Я создал 2 функции по заполнению и выводу массива, но что то не работает, подскажите в чем проблема, я просто новичок в СИ

```
#include <stdio.h>
void create_mas(int **array,int i,int j) {
    int b = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        for (int l = 0; l < j; ++l) {
            b++;
            array[k][l] = b;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
void  show_array(int **array, int i, int j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < j; l++) {
            printf("%d", k);
            printf("%d\t", array[k][l]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
int mas[4][4];
int main() {
    
    create_mas(mas,4, 4);
    show_array(mas,4,4);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701489/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba

Comment: Замечание: у тебя в инициализации массива и потом в функциях используются числа 4. И если ты изменишь одно из них, тебе придется не забыть сделать аналогичную замену еще в двух местах. Ты 100% забудешь это сделать. Так вот чтобы не было таких забот и проблем придумали переменные.

Comment: Смотрите на такой массив внутри функции, как на одномерный `void create_mas(int *array,int i,int j) { int b = 0;    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {  for (int l = 0; l < j; ++l) { b++;      array[k * j + l] = b;    } } return 0; }` А вызывайте вот так `create_mas(&mas[0][0],4, 4);`

Answer (score 2):

Надо либо использовать динамический двумерный массив, что-то типа следующего кода для массива NxM:

```
int** a = (int **) calloc(N, sizeof(int *));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = (int *) calloc(M, sizeof(int));
```

и тогда можно передавать его в функцию `func(int**)`. Потом только надо не забыть освободить выделенную память,

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) free(a[i]);
free(a);
```

Либо передавать в функцию матрицу

```
void show_array(int a[][4]);
```

и тогда ваш код будет работать.

Либо передавать

```
void show_array(int *a);
```

и обращаться к элементу `a[i][j]` как к

```
*(a+4*i+j)
```

Смотрите сами, какой из трех вариантов вам удобнее.